# SAS code for multiple entries of primary key and corresponding data

Tags: sas

I have data like below

```
p_id  E_id
----  ----
1     1  
1     2
1     3
1     4
2     1
3     1
3     2
3     3
4     1
```

For each `primary_id` I have to create a table of the corresponding `E_id`.

How do I do it in SAS;

I am using:

```
  proc freq data = abc;
     where p_id = 1;
     tables p_id * E_id;
  run;
```

How do I generalize the where statement for all the primary keys??

Comment: It would help if you showed us what you want your output to look like if Joe's answer is not what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

The `by` statement is how you get a separate table for each ID.  It requires data to be sorted by the variable.

```
proc freq data = abc;
  by p_id;
  tables p_id * E_id; 
run;
```

Comment: My data is almost 50,000 entries. How do I pick the p_id with more than one entries. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @noshi that doesn't seem to be your original question. I would consider asking a new question if you need a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution allowing you to select `p_id` to generate frequency tables.

```
data have;
  input p_id e_id;
  datalines;
  1      1  
  1      2
  1      3
  1      4
  2      1
  3      1
  3      2
  3      3
  4      1
  ;
run;

proc sort data = have;
  by p_id;
run;

%let pid_list = (1,2); ** only generate two tables;
data _null_;
  set have;
  by p_id;
  if first.p_id and p_id in &pid_list then do;
    call execute('
                proc freq data = have(where = (p_id = '||p_id||'));
                    tables p_id * e_id;
                run;
                ');
  end;
run;
```